# How to mutually share values without influencing senders

Tags: encryption

## Goal

I want Alice and Bob to communicate a message without their answers influencing each other. More formally:

- Alice wants to send Bob a message, `a`.
- Bob wants to send Alice a message, `b`.
- But Alice must not know `b` before sending `a`
- And Bob must not know `a` before sending `b`.

## Attempt

I was thinking I could have:

- Alice sends an encrypted message, `f(a, p1) = a'`, and a hash with the original message and the private key, `h(a, p1)`.
- Bob also sends an encrypted message, `f(b, p2) = b'` and hash, `h(b, p2)`.
- Alice and Bob exchange private keys once they have received their messages
- They decrypt the received messages and verify the hash matches

Is there any problems with this method? Would it be feasible for Alice to construct a `p'` that causes the message to be decrypted as something other than `a` yet still satisfy the hashing function? (assuming cryptographically secure `f` and `h`)

Are there more commonly accepted ways to do this?

---

*previously posted in security stack exchange but was told it'd be more appropriate here*

Comment: Also have a look at [this Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26979/23623).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a [*commitment scheme*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commitment_scheme).
Typically these are a pair of functions $c(m), v(c,m')$ where the first creates a commitment (while not leaking information on $m$) and the latter verifies a commitment against a message.

Let $c(\cdot)$ be such a committing algorithm, then you can use the following protocol:

\begin{align}
A\to B:\quad &c(a)\\
B\to A:\quad &b\\
A\to B:\quad &a
\end{align}

In this case, A doesn't know $b$ when sending $a$, and B doesn't know $a$ when sending $b$. When A then sends $a$, B can verify that this $a$ is indeed the $a$, A commited to earlier and thus that it wasn't chosen in dependence of $b$.